# Certificate Problem (Security Related?!?)

Tags: azure

I'm trying to enumerate certificates from Azure within a web role (running on the v1.3 Azure SDK Dev Fabric) but no certificates are returned when I use the following code.  It's important to note, however, that code works fine when run from a console program:

```
private static void EnumCerts()
{
    var selectedCerts = new X509Certificate2Collection();

    var store = new X509Store(
        StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

    try
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
            Console.WriteLine(cert.Subject);
    }
    finally
    {
        store.Close();
    }
}
```

My working assumption is that this is due to a security issue.  My web role is running with Elevated Trust but I'm guessing that the IIS web instances are not.

In either case I have no idea how to solve the problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by embedding the certificate in my service code then reading it from the resource:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace AcsTest.Shared
{
    public static class CertHelper
    {
        public static X509Certificate2 GetCertFromManifest(
            Assembly assembly, string certName, string password)
        {
            byte[] bytes;

            using (var stream = assembly.
                GetManifestResourceStream(certName))
            {
                bytes = new BinaryReader(stream).
                    ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            }

            return new X509Certificate2(bytes, password,
                X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
        }
    }
}
```

The key insight was that I'd need to store a password in my service to load the cert from the certificate store so I was gaining no security advantage by keeping it in the store.

Answer (score 0):

Store the X509 certificate in the LocalMachine instead of CurrentUser.  CurrentUser for an IIS process runs within the context of IIS-user who you likely have no access to.
Also, you want to make sure that you've imported the certificate on the Azure side into certificate store properly by remoting-in and verifying.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I was under the impression that Azure only stores certificates in the CurrentUser store (as described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/01/29/installing-certificates-in-windows-azure-vms.aspx).  I'll upload an experimental site to test out your theory

Answer (score 0):

You should remote (RDP) into the role and check the store(s).  I honestly don't know where Azure portal uploads certs, but I thought it was CurrentUser (which I think IIS runs under as well).

You can also enumerate the certificates via the Service Management API, which may or may not work for your solution. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795178.aspx